# Three.js r132 'getDirectionalDirectLightIrradiance' & 'getPointDirectLightIrradiance' no matching overloaded function found error

Tags: three.js, fragment-shader

I recently upgraded Three.js from r131 to r132 and I am receiving the following error:

```
Program Info Log: Fragment shader is not compiled.


FRAGMENT

ERROR: 0:459: 'getDirectionalDirectLightIrradiance' : no matching overloaded function found
ERROR: 0:479: 'getPointDirectLightIrradiance' : no matching overloaded function found
```

The relevant parts of my fragment shader is below:

```c
    IncidentLight directLight;

    // Directional Light
    #if NUM_DIR_LIGHTS > 0

        DirectionalLight directionalLight;

        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_DIR_LIGHTS; i++) {

            directionalLight = directionalLights[i];

            getDirectionalDirectLightIrradiance(directionalLight, geometry, directLight);

            #ifdef USE_SHADOWMAP
                directLight.color *= all(bvec2(directionalLight.shadow, directLight.visible)) ? getShadow(directionalShadowMap[i], directionalLight.shadowMapSize, directionalLight.shadowBias, directionalLight.shadowRadius, vDirectionalShadowCoord[i]) : 1.0;
            #endif

            RE_Direct(directLight, geometry, material, reflectedLight);
        }

    #endif

    // Point Light
    #if (NUM_POINT_LIGHTS > 0)

        PointLight pointLight;

        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_POINT_LIGHTS; i++) {

            pointLight = pointLights[i];

            getPointDirectLightIrradiance(pointLight, geometry, directLight);

            #ifdef USE_SHADOWMAP
                directLight.color *= all(bvec2(pointLight.shadow, directLight.visible)) ? getPointShadow(pointShadowMap[i], pointLight.shadowMapSize, pointLight.shadowBias, pointLight.shadowRadius, vPointShadowCoord[i]) : 1.0;
            #endif

            RE_Direct(directLight, geometry, material, reflectedLight);
        }

    #endif
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking into a recent [commit](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/commit/f753126563a1e5ed9681b9b895ddae29eea830cb), it seems they renamed `getDirectionalDirectLightIrradiance` to `getDirectionalLightInfo` and renamed `getPointDirectLightIrradiance` to `getPointLightInfo` among other things.

renaming these methods fixed the issue.